# Linux add listener to the log file

Tags: linux, logging

Is there a better way to monitor for file log changes that using inotify? (http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify). I have several software that writes to different log files and I want to go POST query every time the new line is added to the log.

Currently, my proposal is to set inotify to listen for file changes, get data that was changed since last visit and do post.

Things that are important: 
Reaction to event (at least 1 second).
Low CPU and HDD consumption.
Keeping log file (i.e. I want it to be on the machine full, unmodified).

New lines are added once in 1 min.

Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inotify is fine for getting notified about file events such as writing etc but how will you know how much data has been appended? If you know the log files in advance you might as well read until end of file and just sleep for a short while and try again to read (something like "tail -f" does). That way you still have the pointer to where you start to read the newly written data. You could even combine that with Inotify to know when to pick up reading. If you want to just use Inotify, you probably will have to store the pointers to the last read position somewhere.

Comment: I wanted to read this form the end (think that such thing exist) and stop by string comparison (or date comparison or pointer). One thing I am not sure about -tail is that I will load HDD every iteration.